# how to load a diferrent php file dynamically based on the browser window's width using jQuery or any other method

Tags: php, jquery, browser, resolution

Hello friends a very novice question as I am very new to programming.

I was browsing the web and found a method to dynamically load a CSS file based on the browser width.

**jQuery**

```
function adjustStyle(width) {
    width = parseInt(width);
    if (width < 701) {
        $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/narrow.css");
    } else if ((width >= 701) && (width < 900)) {
        $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/medium.css");
    } else {
       $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/wide.css"); 
    }
}

$(function() {
    adjustStyle($(this).width());
    $(window).resize(function() {
        adjustStyle($(this).width());
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
<link id="size-stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="narrow.css" />
```

I want to know, can I use the same to load a `php file`?

If yes what will be the code look like?

I think we will be required to use something like `<?php require_once('http://mysite.com/layouts/ipad.php'); ?>` but how do I code it?

Kindly help.

Regards

Comment: Why would you want to load a php file to browser ?

Comment: Basically I want a diferrent layout depending on the browser even the content will change depending on the browser.

Comment: before using ajax you should understand how web works. There is no difference between an HTML provided by PHP,ASP or any other scripting language or CGI application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know, can I use the same to load a php file?

If by "load a php file" you mean load a different page where you'll define different pages for different conditions (widths, whatever), then you can load different pages by setting [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) equal to the desired page. This will replace the current page with the one you specify.

I don't think you should do this every time the window is resized though. If you must do it at least check whether the new size actually requires a change rather than repeatedly reloading it regardless.

Following is similar to your existing code:

```
function setLocation(url) {
   if (window.location.href.indexOf(url) === -1)
      window.location = url;
}

function reloadPage(width) {
    width = parseInt(width);
    if (width < 701) {
        setLocation("yournarrowpage.php");
    } else if (width < 900) {
        setLocation("yourmediumpage.php");
    } else {
        setLocation("yourwidepage.php");
    }
}

$(function() {
   reloadPage($(this).width());
   $(window).resize(function() {
       reloadPage($(this).width());
   });
});
```

You don't have to reload the entire page each time though, you can reload just certain sections using ajax. For that you could do something similar to the above except instead of setting `window.location` you'd use [jQuery's `.load() method`](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
function setLocation(url) {
   $("selector for the element to reload").load(url);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what you're actually wanting to do is redirect the user to a different page based on browser or resolution.

```
$(document).load(function() {
    var $width = $(window).width()
    if($width < 701)
        window.location = 'narrow.php'
    else if($width < 900)
        window.location = 'medium.php'
    else
        window.location = 'wide.php'
})
```

You could easily make the same function run on window resize, although it may not work as well as you hope in practice.

Edit: If you're just doing this for iPads specifically (which you shouldn't):

```
if(stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Mozilla/5.0(iPad;')) {
     // probably an iPad
     require('ipad.php');
     //Or maybe the below might serve you better:
     /*
     header('Location:ipad.php');
     die();
     */
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. Yes I am trying to divert a visitor to a diferrent php file based on the browser width because even the content changes. Please dont mind but I am totally a novice in programming. Your first method looks fine buy how do I call that function in my main `index.php file?` Please help.

Comment: My first is in Javascript (specifically jQuery). Easiest way is to pop it into some <script> tags (and make sure you've got jQuery included too). Note that it won't work if someone has got Javascript disabled.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good starting place for the css question: http://topsecretproject.finitestatemachine.com/2009/09/how-to-load-javascript-and-css-dynamically-with-jquery/

And for loading php, see [Including a php file dynamically with javascript and jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954371/including-a-php-file-dynamically-with-javascript-and-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (width < 701) {
    $.get('yourlayoutfor701.php', function(data) {
    $('#your_layout').html(data);  
    });
 }
```

hope this might help you, but not a good practice